# Bot can't connect to voice channel - discord.py rewrite

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am making a discord bot using the discord.py rewrite and I have recently run into a problem.

I have made a command to join a user's voice channel. The thing is, my command works perfectly fine when I run it on my local PC, but now that I'm trying to run it on a raspberry pi it fails when connecting to the voice channel.

I have tried installing all dependencies but I just can't get it to work.
Code for the command:

```
@bot.command()
async def join(ctx):
    channel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel
    voice = get(bot.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)

    if voice and voice.is_connected():
        await voice.move_to(channel)
    else:
        voice = await channel.connect()

    await ctx.send("I joined the channel!")
```

There are no exceptions raised.

Comment: Does your pi support voice libraries? As well as things such as pynacl

Comment: How would I check that? I didn't receive any errors when installing it.

Comment: were you able to get it to connect?

Comment: Nope, I suppose it's something to do with the raspberry pi, but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 2):

You are using a bad way to connect to the voice channel.
Try using this code.

It identify where the user is and connect in that voice channel.

```
   @bot.command(name='join', invoke_without_subcommand=True)
    async def join(ctx):
       destination = ctx.author.voice.channel
       if ctx.voice_state.voice:
         await ctx.voice_state.voice.move_to(destination)
         return
    
       ctx.voice_state.voice = await destination.connect()
       await ctx.send(f"Joined {ctx.author.voice.channel} Voice Channel")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can run `pip install -U discord.py[voice]` in your terminal. And try using this code.

```
@bot.command(pass_context = True)
async def join(ctx):
    if (ctx.author.voice):
        await ctx.author.voice.channel.connect()
    else:
        await ctx.send("Please Join Voice channel to run this command")

@client.command()
async def leave(ctx):
    await ctx.voice_client.disconnect()
```