# adding a discord.py bot to a voice channel

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am trying to connect my bot to a voice channel using discord.py but it is not working to me so well... any help on how I can improve that?

```
    @bot.command(pass_context=True)
    async def join(ctx):
        channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
        await bot.join_voice_channel(channel)
```

Error :

```
    Ignoring exception in command join:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\matan\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 85, in wrapped
        ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
      File "C:/Users/matan/Desktop/python/discord bot 1/Main.py", line 926, in join
        await bot.join_voice_channel(channel)
    AttributeError: 'Bot' object has no attribute 'join_voice_channel'
```

I also have this code :

```py
    @bot.command()
    async def play(ctx, url : str, channel = discord.VoiceChannel):
        await channel.connect()
```

It has no errors - it is just doing nothing...

Comment: I think you mean `channel: discord.VoiceChannel`, not an assignment `=`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bot can't connect to voice channel - discord.py rewrite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63449645/bot-cant-connect-to-voice-channel-discord-py-rewrite)

Answer (score 1):

To join a channel you use `await VoiceChannel.connect()`

So for your example it would be

```
@bot.command()
async def join(ctx):
    channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
    await channel.connect()
```

Also `pass_context` is deprecated afaik.

For your second example

```
@bot.command()
async def play(ctx, url: str, channel: discord.VoiceChannel):
    await channel.connect()
```

There is just a typo I guess, you have to use a `:` to declare the arguments type.

Comment: I got this error for the first one : 

```Ignoring exception in command join:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\matan\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:/Users/matan/Desktop/python/discord bot 1/Main.py", line 926, in join
    await bot.join_voice_channel(channel)
AttributeError: 'Bot' object has no attribute 'join_voice_channel'```

Comment: Oh sorry copied the wrong Code I edited it, now it should work.